# autocomplete search form cakephp

Tags: php, search, cakephp, autocomplete

Hey there, I'm a total newbie and I'm looking for a way to have a search box with autocomplete just like google does.

I've searched and the best prospect that I've found seems to be http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm which I found on a forum. The guy who suggested it says he uses it with http://code.google.com/p/searchable-behaviour-for-cakephp/ which is dead on because I've managed to install searchable on my last attempt at figuring out cakephp.

The thing is, I've not used much javascript before and I'm a bit confused as to what exactly I'm meant to be doing. The documentation with the autocomplete codes doesn't go into any detail that I can understand.

If we assume that I manage to get searchable behaviour installed correctly, could any kind person explain to me how I would go about making the autocomplete work?

It says to just use:

```
$("selector").autocomplete(url [, options]);
```

eg:

```
$("#input_box").autocomplete("autocomplete_ajax.cfm");
```

Autocomplete expects an input element with the id "input_box" to exist. When a user starts typing in the input box, the autocompleter will request `autocomplete_ajax.cfm` with a GET parameter named `q`

thats the bit I don't get. Where am I meant to put that? And once I've put it somewhere then do I just need to name one of my inputs "`input_box`"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: CakePHP comes with autocomplete built in. Have you tried that? http://book.cakephp.org/view/1370/autoComplete

Comment: Both the JavascriptHelper and the AjaxHelper are deprecated, and the JsHelper + HtmlHelper should be used in their place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three steps:

1) create a totally normal form with an input field, using the Html helper in your view:

```
// app/views/foo_bars/search.ctp
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('FooBar');
echo $this->Form->input('field');
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

2) Have a jquery autocomplete fired:

```
// app/views/foo_bars/search.ctp
<?php
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
    .'$("#FooBarField").autocomplete({'
        .'source:"/foo_bars/find",'
        .'delay: 100,'
        .'select:function(event,ui){$(this).parent().parent().children("input").val(ui.item.id);},'
        .'open:function(event,ui){$(this).parent().parent().children("input").val(0);}'
    .'});'
    array('inline' => false));
?>
```

3) Query a database through a controller to get possible values:

```
// app/controllers/foo_bars_controller.php
<?php
public function find() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->autoLayout = false;
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->FooBar->recursive = -1;
        $results = $this->FooBar->find('all', array('fields' => array('id', 'name'), 'conditions' => array('name LIKE "%'.$_GET['term'].'%"')));
        $response = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($results as $result){
            $response[$i]['value'] = $result['FooBar']['name'];
            $response[$i]['id'] = $result['FooBar']['id'];
            $i++;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(

> **'**$("#FooBarField").autocomplete({'

```
    .'source:"/Search/find",'
    .'delay: 100,'
    .'select:function(event,ui){$(this).parent().parent().children("input").val(ui.item.id);},'
    .'open:function(event,ui){$(this).parent().parent().children("input").val(0);}'
```

> .'});**'.**

```
array('inline' => false));
```

Comment: Practically a copy of damusnet answer (part of it at least).